# Migrating data and metadata to a developer org

Tags: migration, developer-edition

I would like to use a developer org for development. Can anyone let me know how data and meta data of the production org be copied to the developer org?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need two separate pieces here and quite a bit more manual work, since developer editions cannot use change sets and cannot be cloned off of a production edition as a sandbox can.

1. You need a deployment tool or IDE to retrieve the metadata from production and push it into the developer edition. (Note that if you're seriously trying to retrieve the entire org, you'll probably have some work to do to make your Developer Edition look like production before you can even deploy). The currently supported IDE is Visual Studio Code with the Salesforce DX Extension Pack. Other options include Illuminated Cloud, ForceCLI, and the now-deprecated MavensMate and Force.com IDE. I would recommend searching SFSE for the numerous past questions about how to do large-scale or org-wide retrievals.
2. You need a data migration tool, and you need to define a process to pull a subset of your production data and upload it to your org (a full copy will not fit in a developer edition). You can do this by hand with the Data Loader and optionally the weekly export files, you can use a commercial tool like OwnBackup or Gearset, or you can use a free and open source [data loader I wrote, Amaxa](https://gitlab.com/davidmreed/amaxa). Any way you slice it, this will be a fairly manual and perhaps frustrating process; you may reconsider whether you need real data in your development environment.

Setting aside the data angle and using [Salesforce DX with scratch orgs](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model) will, at least in some ways, dramatically simplify your process. Alternately, just use a sandbox, since that's what they're designed to do out of the box.

Comment: Thank you David.